# How to read a .txt file character by character without <iostream>?

Tags: c++

I have an assignment that requires us to reformat a text file that is given to us. The program is ran using the cmd, and is given two command parameters; a number, and the name of a text file. My job is to write a function that will format the text file, and display it in a specific format. However, I'm having a very very hard time even getting started.

I am ONLY allowed to edit this function, and only allowed to add code between these two brackets;

```
void typeset (int maxWidth, istream& documentIn)
{

}
```

I am completely lost on what to do. I've spent the past hour and a half trying various things, but none of them work. I'm not sure how the syntax works. Above the 'void typeset', is more code, but I am not allowed to alter it. Here's what's at the beginning of the .cpp

```
#include "typeset.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

I've got no idea how to do the bit where I 'read' the text file. What I'd like to do is have a loop that continuously reads characters until there's a space, saves that string of characters as a word, and continues to do so until it reaches the end of the file. Everything I've found uses something like std::ifstream, which doesn't seem to work. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Post what you tried and explain exactly what "doesn't work" mean. There's bazillions of examples of reading from text files all over the place, please do a bit more research too. And your title doesn't match the body, why do you want to avoid iostream when you're passed an istream?

Comment: Whoops, sorry. The `#include <iostream>` isn't supposed to be there, I added that in to see if that would fix anything, but I forgot to remove it. And yes, I checked for those examples, but I wasn't able to find any that would work. I don't understand how I'm supposed to use `istream& documentIn`

Comment: Here's an example of what I tried.
'std::ifstream file(documentIn);
std::string temp;
std::getline(file, temp);'

There were a lot more things I attempted, but I deleted them after they didn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you tried, and describe **exactly** what "doesn't work" mean. Compiler error? If yes, post the error too. Runtime error? If yes, post what error. Doesn't do what you expect? Post what you expect, and what you get instead, and show the sample data that produced it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seem to be a lack of understanding of how streams work. You are **not** supposed to create your own ifstream, you are supposed to use the `istream&` supplied to the function

Write some code like this to read the document one character at a time

```
void typeset (int maxWidth, istream& documentIn)
{
    char ch;
    while (documentIn.get(ch))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

To me your confusion seems to characterise someone who just looks on the internet for something close to what they want to do. At some point you have to get a more fundamental understanding of C++, so that you can understand code and write original code, instead of just copying and modifying code. You're only going to get that by reading a textbook, which explains the principles behind C++.

In this case the principle is that all the different input streams *derive* from `istream` so input from any kind of stream can be done with an `istream`.

Comment: This works like a charm. Turns out the actual reason I couldn't get it to run was an operator error; I had the text file in the wrong folder, and was so focused on my code that I didn't think about the file. Thank you!